running Navigation stack on clearpath warthog
I am trying to run the Navigation stack on a clearpath warthog. I know it is possible with other cleatpath robots but I have not seen a package for the warthog. Has anyone had any success on getting this working?

Please provide specific information like what ROS version you are running and which navigation stack that you would like to run with it. The high level answer is that yes you can use Warthogs with autonomous navigation but beyond that all details depend on the specifics. The robot always needs to have compatible sensors with the navigation package. For ROS 2 there is documentation here on how to run the Nav2 demos: https://docs.clearpathrobotics.com/docs/ros/tutorials/navigation_demos/overview
